# mysql 5.6 is Not referring Indexes for deterministic function DATEDIFF

Tags: index, optimization, mysql-5.6, functions

I do not understand why MySQL is not using the index for the below query.

I have a table named `users` and its create table is

[image]

this table contains data.

Now I am running SQL select statements and it's checking its query execution plan.

for the statement

```
desc select *
     from   users
     where  users.created_at between '2019-05-04' and '2019-05-06';
```

output is [image]

but which I am using `DateDiff` function query is not using indexes.

```
desc select *
     from   users
     where  DATEDIFF(users.created_at,'2019-05-05 23:11:56.547') =  0;
```

and output for this is [image]

according to the MySQL documentation page "*A function is nondeterministic if, given fixed values for its arguments, it can return different results for different invocations*".

According to [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/function-optimization.html), `DateDiff` is a deterministic function and I am not understanding why MySQL is not taking indexes for the query.

Comment: A deterministic function is needed for a generated column which you can also index. But MySQL does not know how to turn a function into a rangenscan for the underlying base column (index)

Comment: So how can I Fix this? By adding a index something like this ?

Comment: Users(DateDiff(created_at)) ??? DateDiff requires two values. In my case one is table value and other is constant. And constant values can change on time.

Comment: So how should I make a derived coloum ?

Comment: You probably can’t use datediff if the constant changes. In this case it’s easier to have a column (derived or primary) which contains a flexible number representation (millis since epoch) instead, then you can use numerical compares which work with index.

Comment: The index can be used only in case when the index expression (or its prefix) is fully literally equal to the condition expression part. In the last query the condition expression part `DATEDIFF(users.created_at,'2019-05-05 23:11:56.547')` is not equal to index expression ``(`created_at`)``, so this index cannot be used.

Comment: @Akina So How can I make the index ( i.e index expression) for the above conditional expression?

Comment: No. The literal datetime which you use will be changed for each query, is it?

Comment: Yes, literal DateTime will change for each query. I need to make an index in such a way whatever constant is used indexes should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for indexes not being used is table column is an input part of the function.
Current SQL Query

```
select *
 from   users
 where  DATEDIFF(users.created_at,'2019-05-05 23:11:56.547') =  0;
```

Indexes will be used if the query is in below way

```
select *
 from   users
 where  users.created_at =  DATE_ADD('2019-05-05 23:11:56.547', INTERVAL 0 DAY);
```

since above refers to a point of time. To check day we can have to use range timestamp start of today to start off tomorrow,

```
select *
 from   users
 where  users.created_at between DATE_ADD('2019-05-05 ', INTERVAL 0 DAY)
and DATE_ADD('2019-05-05 ', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```